# Javascript - 2 statements for one condition

Tags: javascript, netsuite, statements, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to allow my prices to display under 2 conditions

1. sales price must be less than the base price
2. "don't show pricing is unchecked" (yes or no) in our system

   ```
   var basPrc = "$5000";
   var onlnPrc = "<%=getAttribute('item','382798','salesprice')%>";
   var CallForPrice = "<%=getAttribute('item','382798','dontshowprice')%>";

   if (onlnPrc < basPrc || CallForPrice == "No") { 
    document.write('<span class="strike">Base Price: <span>'+basPrc+'</span></span>')
    document.write("<br /><strong class=\"saleprice\">Our Price: <%=getAttribute('item','382798','salesprice')%></strong><br />");
   //savings
   var savings = onlnPrc - basPrc;
   document.write ('<span class="save">You Save: <span class="red">'+ savings +'</span></span><br />');
    }
      //if don't show pricing is checked
       if (CallForPrice = "Yes") { 
         var basPrc = null;
         var onlnPrc = null;
        document.write('<br /><strong class="saleprice">Call For Pricing<strong><br />');
       }


    //if no online pricing
    else {document.write('<br /><strong class="saleprice">Our Price: '+basPrc+' <strong><br />');}
   ```

I tried the "&&" operators and no luck, any idea on what I should do next?

Comment: Consider using `===`, even.

Comment: I actually just did that, I managed to get it to work! Now I gotta fix the NaN issue. the Math.subtract() doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `basPrc` is a String, not a Number; you should initialize it to `5000`, not `"$5000"` (the lack of quotes being important here). I'm not sure at all what `onlnPrc` will be. You need to make sure both are numbers. Otherwise, when you do `basPrc > onlnPrc` you will be doing a String comparison, not a numeric one.

```
// Base Price defaults to 5000
var basPrc = 5000;

// Parse the Online Price as a floating point number;
// if the result is NaN, default it to 0
var onlnPrc = parseFloat("<%=getAttribute('item','382798','salesprice')%>") || 0;
```

You should endeavor to make sure that `basPrc` and `onlnPrc` are always numbers since you are doing calculations with them. Leave the display of currency symbols or decimal points to the pieces of the code where you actually display the data.

Unrelated question: Where does this code live? What's it for? I've never seen NetSuite code that looked anything like this.

Comment: This looks like a client side script or a suitelet since he is accessing the DOM.

Comment: Which brings me to my next question of - why not use a client script?